# Summer20 - recordEditForm issues

Tags: cache, lightning-recordeditform, summer20

We are facing some issues with **Summer20** releases. Does anybody face those issues?

1. **Scrollbar is not visible on Edit(overridden component) screen** - But *with hard refresh its showing scrollbar*(tried with 2 different sandboxes same behavior but with scratch org with spring20, no such behavior).

   ***Steps to reproduce -***

   1. Have a recordEditForm with New it's working properly.
   2. Once I go to the detail page and open edit(overridden) component. It is not showing scrollbar.
   3. Now I click `Ctrl+Shift+R` (hard refresh), scrollbar is visible. Each time I need to do hard refresh.
2. **Caching the forms** - E.g. We have a new form overridden, but when we cancel and again click on the New button, its showing earlier data only. However, I resolved this by adding refreshview explicitly.
3. **`recordTypeId` mandatory** - Earlier we have not provided default record type id, it was working fine. But with summer20 it is not saving the record, on Submit its loading spinner and going in an infinite loop, however with `recordTypeId`, it is resolved.

*The scrollbar issue is not having any solution*. Does anybody have any workaround on that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For #2 I guess the refreshView/refreshApex is the only option. Also for #3, as per the docs, `recordTypeId` is required only when you have multiple record types on an object and you don't have a default record type.

Comment: yes if multiple we need to give, we had only 1 record type that too defaults for all.